# Django charfield problem not returning value of text

Tags: python, django

So the above code contains variable text which stores the 'Topic' name but as i enter the topic name in django site admin it never shows  the text rather than it stores and display "object(1) is successfully stored"

```
    from django.db import models

    class Topic(models.Model):
        """A topic the user is learning about"""
        text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text
```

Comment: You sure that you've indented `def __str__` to be within the `class` block?

Answer (score 0):

the method seems okay, but if the formatting in your code is the same as here that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the end of your Topic model

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

#self.text is what will display instead of the object(1)